# How to get my program to read a text file properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, variables

Basically, I'm trying to get my program to read and display a list of grades from a file in the same folder called (grades.txt). Issue is, is the for some reason I keep getting an Index error no matter what I do. I've tried moving the text file in a different directory, I tried changing the parameters of what the program is supposed to read, I tried editing the process for looking at the file too; but NOTHING is working! I keep getting the Index Error again! What am I doing wrong here?! Any help would be very appreciated as I am pulling my hair out!

```
END_OF_LINE = ""
EMPTY = ""
NEWLINE = "\n"
SPACE = " "


def display(grades, numRows, numColumns):
    currentRow = 0
    currentColumn = 0
    total = 0
    average = 0
    while (currentRow < numRows):
        total = 0
        average = 0
        currentColumn = 0
        while (currentColumn < numColumns):
            print("%s" % grades[currentRow][currentColumn], end=SPACE)
            total = total + int(grades[currentRow][currentColumn])
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
        average = total / numColumns
        print("\tAverage=%.2f" % (average))
        currentRow = currentRow + 1


def fileRead():
    fileOK = False
    grades = []
    maxColumns = 0
    while (fileOK == False):
        try:
            filename = input("Name of input file: ")
            inputfile = open(filename, "r")
            fileOK = True
            aLine = inputfile.readline()
            if (aLine == EMPTY):
                print("%s is an empty file")
            else:
                aLine = inputfile.readline()
                currentRow = 0
                while (aLine != END_OF_LINE):
                    currentCharacter = 0
                    grades.append([])
                    while (aLine[currentCharacter] != NEWLINE):
                        # Only add grades not spaces to the list of grade points
                        if (aLine[currentCharacter] != SPACE):
                            grades[currentRow].append(aLine[currentCharacter])
                        currentCharacter = currentCharacter + 1
                    currentRow = currentRow + 1
                    aLine = inputfile.readline()
                inputfile.close()
        except IOError:
            print("Problem reading from file %s" % (filename))
            fileOK = False
    numRows = currentRow
    numColumns = len(grades[0])
    return (grades, numRows, numColumns)


def start():
    grades, numRows, numColumns = fileRead()
    display(grades, numRows, numColumns)


start()
```

Error:

```
Name of input file: grades.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:", line 68, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:", line 64, in start
    grades, numRows, numColumns = fileRead()
  File "C:", line 47, in fileRead
    while (aLine[currentCharacter] != NEWLINE):
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Grades.txt

```
Spring 2020 Grades for CPSC 217 Lecture
4 4 3 2 0
4 4 4 4 3
```

Comment: likely the last line of the file doesn't have a newline character, so it's failing on the `currentCharacter` part. But you should use `string.split()`. Your logic can be simplified to a couple of lines.

Answer (score 0):

the fileread function can be shortened a lot, as you can use "normal" string manipulation to do everything you're doing with your custom logic.

and just to point out what is the problem with your current logic, the file you're reading does not end with a newline character, which is very common in files.

```py
def fileRead(filename):
    with open(filename) as infile:
        # read the whole file and split on newline characters
        data = infile.read().splitlines()
    if len(data) > 1:
        result = []
        for line in data[1:]:
            result.append(line.split())
        if len(result) > 0:
            return result
    print("invalid file")
```

The same goes for the other function. You're basically trying to re-invent the wheel while python has a lot of standard string/list/math things that make it a lot easier

```py
def display(grades):
    for line in grades:
        print(" ".join(line))
        average = sum([int(grade) for grade in line]) / len(line)
        print(f"\tAverage={average:.2f}")
```

**EDIT**

to tie it into your logic, change your start function into the more pythonic dunder main magic.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = input("please provide a file name:\n")
    grades = fileRead(filename)
    display(grades)
```

I would read up on what the so-called dunder main does, fe [here](https://medium.com/python-features/understanding-if-name-main-in-python-a37a3d4ab0c3)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But one issue, the filename parameter is not defined.

Comment: Also, where would the user input the file name?

Comment: see my edit, do rad up on what dunder main does

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! This was killing me!!